# Gutenberg get wp registered sidebars

Tags: sidebar, block-editor

In my template I have registered several sidebars with function `register_sidebar()`.

Now I am looking for a way how to get list of all registered sidebars in Gutenberg. I was looking in documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/ but didn't find anything useful.

Is it even possible to get such a data in Gutenberg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is not passed into Gutenberg by default. You should create custom REST API endpoint and data store. [This article](https://mattwatson.codes/articles/working-with-gutenberg-and-the-wordpress-rest-api/) might help with some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to create custom **shortcode** in the WordPress to getting registered/custom sidebar, so that you can display this sidebar anywhere over the website using shortcode.